# Parse through JSON using only Bash

Tags: json, bash, sed, jq, cut

I have a JSON file :

```
{
    "request_id": "9a081c0c-9401-7eca-f55d-50e3b7c0301c",
    "lease_id": "",
    "renewable": false,
    "lease_duration": 2764800,
    "data": {
        "password": "test123",
        "username": "testuser1"
    },
    "wrap_info": null,
    "warnings": null,
    "auth": null
}
```

I am trying to read the values of `username` and `password`. Now I was able to integrate bash and python to get what I wanted.

```
# curl --silent -k https://1.2.3.4:8200/v1/secret/service/clustered -H "X-Vault-Token: c2e3b6ec17df" | python3 -c "import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)['data']['password'])"
test123

# curl --silent -k https://1.2.3.4:8200/v1/secret/service/clustered -H "X-Vault-Token: c2e3b6ec17df" | python3 -c "import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)['data']['username'])"
testuser1
```

But since I only want to use bash, I have done the following too:

```
# curl --silent -k https://1.2.3.4:8200/v1/secret/service/clustered -H "X-Vault-Token: c2e3b6ec17df" | sed -n -e 's/^.*password":"//p' | cut -d'"' -f1
test123

# curl --silent -k https://1.2.3.4:8200/v1/secret/service/clustered -H "X-Vault-Token: c2e3b6ec17df" | sed -n -e 's/^.*username":"//p' | cut -d'"' -f1
testuser
```

I am just concerned whether I have made use of `sed` and `cut` commands correctly in this case. Or is there a better way to extract the required fields?

Comment: Why would you want to use `sed`, use `jq` a son syntax aware parser.

Comment: Sed and `cut` are not "only Bash", they're external dependencies. If you really want a parser that's written in shell, you can have a look at [JSON.sh](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSON.sh).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would recommend using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/):

```
$ jq '.data.password' data.json
"test123"
```

Or both fields:

```
$ jq '.data.password, .data.username' data.json
"test123"
"testuser1"
```

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend  `jq` a lightweight `JSON` aware parser for manipulating `JSON` content. Pipe your `curl` command input to a filter in `jq` as

```
curl-command | jq --raw-output '.data.password, .data.username'
```

Instructions to [download-and-install `jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) available.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? I'd be happy to correct if some information were incorrect

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bashJson](https://github.com/hack4mer/bashjson)

Its a wrapper for the Python's JSON module and can handle complex JSON data.

See my answer here for example usage : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51821898/2734348