# How to parse an output enclosed with braces?

Tags: shell, parsing

So, I am writing a shell script and I am running a command that gives me an output like:

```
{"a":"some_text","b":some_other_text","c":"even_more_text"}
```

Now, I am not sure how to parse it, I basically need the value of "c", i.e. "ever_more_text" in a variable, but finding out results on internet have not worked yet! TIA.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44032450/parse-through-json-using-only-bash

Comment: So, JSON? Look into using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to extract what you need.

Comment: @Pensu : You have also to state, whether the string to be parsed is always such a simple one, or whether it may contain nested braces.

Answer (score 0):

the output which you paste here is not valid json. Check with https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ There is missing first double quote in `"some_other_text"`. If you add it, you can then easily parse with `jq`:

```
./your_script.sh | jq -r ".c"
```